# Split up a page

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, documentation-examples

With the move to limit the number of examples in a documentation page, it becomes important be able to easily restructure pages.

Please provide a simple way to move an example from one page to another, maintaining the votes (upvotes/downvotes) and comments.

Even if the current severe limit on examples is overturned, this "migrate" feature is useful for other situations.  Here's another:

A page on "foo-bar" is built and populated. Then someone builds a page on "bar-foo" and it gets populated.  Eventually someone notices and wants to merge the two pages, taking the best from each.

Comment: "*Please provide a simple way to move an example from one page to another, maintaining the votes (upvotes/downvotes) and comments.*" You can already move examples from topic to topic by editing them and clicking "move to topic" at the top of the example.